# Change project settings after footage is all cut up on Premiere Elements

Tags: premiere, premiere-elements

I've spent a couple of hours cutting and editing gopro footage, unfortunately the first file I added to the timeline was the soundtrack.

Now my project resolution and frame rate are wrong and I can't adjust it in order to just select "4k UHD" in render options using mp4 - XAVC-S because it defaults to 60fps

Two questions :

1. Is there a way, even hacky, to change project settings for an existing project?
2. If not, how can I render with same UHD xavc-s settings but just change the frame rate? It's not always letting me select even the correct resolution in 'custom'.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to adjust everything just from the project panel.
See this, I dropped mp3 into 'new timeline' button and got this sequence -

[image: autosequence]

All you need to do is go to sequence and select desired output
[image]

You can set everything here
[image]

For me, making the MP3 file into 'New sequence' defaulted in 1920x1080 29.97 sequence, but if you have issue that it made different format and you want to skip changing scale of every individual file (I'm assuming you might have got different format, like 1280x720, although unlikely), you can just setup an adjustment file above your edit, select 'distort - > transform' from effects and adjust scale to fit to your desired resolution.